# IntelliJ 2019.1 can't find persistence.xml (added to Project's Classpath)

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, junit5, persistence.xml

To test a Hibernate/OGM/MongoDB Docker issue I've created a JUnit5 test.

I've added the persistence.xml to the project in the folder:

> src/test/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">


    <persistence-unit name="goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <properties>

            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.3"/>

            <property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="org.hibernate.search.orm:5.10"/>

            <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossTS"/> -->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAS"/> -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                      value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider"
                      value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect"
                      value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="goStopHandleDB"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="172.17.0.2:32844"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I've gone into the project settings and under:

> modules | myProject_test | JPA

I've '+' the persistence.xml

Which appears as a 'JPA Configuration Descriptor', so it should now be in the classpath?

However When I run the test I get:

> Apr 08, 2019 2:36:54 PM
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser doResolve INFO:
>   HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the
>   classpath Apr 08, 2019 2:36:54 PM
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser doResolve INFO:
>   HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the
>   classpath
>
> Test ignored.
>
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit
>
> at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
>     at
>   com.gostophandle.entity.MotorcycleTest.init(MotorcycleTest.java:25)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$9(ClassTestDescriptor.java:376)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassTestDescriptor.java:375)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Any ideas why the persistence.xml is not being found? TIA.

BTW - The persistence.xml all works fine when deployed in an EAR on JBoss WildFly 16.0.0.Final and it accesses my MongoDB database using JPA: Hibernate/OGM.

I'm having some issues accessing MongoDB in a Docker container and it's been suggested (by Red Hat) I test the MongoClient generated by Hibernate OGM.

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard `src/test/resources` resource root directory, especially if you are using a build system like Maven.

It should work if the `persistence.xml` is placed in `src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`.

Comment: Did try that originally and didn't work. I'm running the Unit test from within Intelli? Right clicked on test method name and 'run xxxxx'. Have re-tried and get the same error "INFO: HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath".

Comment: How did you set up the project, using IntelliJ or by importing a build tool config e.g. Maven?

Comment: Also my: Gradle test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}
fails with 'com.gostophandle.entity.MotorcycleTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at MotorcycleTest.java:25'
on the line: entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit" );

Comment: It's a long-standing project where all the other unit tests (web services) run fine inside IntelliJ and also in my Gradle Build. My Gradle build creates the WAR, JAR & EAR which deploys fine to JBoss WildFly. Just added a new unit test to try and connect to MongoDB directly and the persisence.xml not found issue started.